# How to encode video 3840x2160 with 32x32 and 16x16 CU with depth 2 and 1 in HEVC Encoder HM 13

Tags: encoder, hevc

When I try to encode a video the encoder crashes after finishing first GOP.

This is the configuration I'm using:

```
MaxCUWidth                    : 16          # Maximum coding unit width in pixel
MaxCUHeight                   : 16          # Maximum coding unit height in pixel
MaxPartitionDepth             : 2           # Maximum coding unit depth
QuadtreeTULog2MaxSize         : 3           # Log2 of maximum transform size for 
                                            # quadtree-based TU coding (2...5) = MaxPartitionDepth + 2 - 1
QuadtreeTULog2MinSize         : 2           # Log2 of minimum transform size for
                                            # quadtree-based TU coding (2...5)
QuadtreeTUMaxDepthInter       : 1           
QuadtreeTUMaxDepthIntra       : 1  

#======== Coding Structure =============
IntraPeriod                   : 8          # Period of I-Frame ( -1 = only first)

DecodingRefreshType           : 1           # Random Accesss 0:none, 1:CDR, 2:IDR

GOPSize                       : 4           # GOP Size (number of B slice = GOPSize-1)

#        Type POC QPoffset QPfactor tcOffsetDiv2 betaOffsetDiv2 temporal_id #ref_pics_active #ref_pics reference pictures     predict deltaRPS #ref_idcs reference idcs 
Frame1:  P    4   1        0.5      0            0               0           1                1         -4                 0

Frame2:  B    2   2        0.5      1            0               1           1                2         -2 2               1       2        2         1 1

Frame3:  B    1   3        0.5      2            0               2           1                3         -1 1 3             1       1        3         1 1 1

Frame4:  B    3   3        0.5      2            0               2           1                2         -1 1               1       -2       4         0 1 1 0
```

This also happens with `CU=16x16` with `depth=1`
*Note*: I encoded `CU=64x64` with `depth=4` with the same GOP configuration and every thing went fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most probably due to the fact that you have compiled the binary for a 32-bit system?

Please rebuild it for a 64-bit system and the problem will go away.